# Want to know relative x path of iframe from below source code

Tags: iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to found the relative `xpath` using below source code of `iframe`.

I have tried with `id= GTM-WDM67TP`, but was not able to find

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="ssoPlatform">

 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Page title set in pageTitle directive -->
<title>Single Sign On</title>
<link rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon/innoplexus.png" type="image/png">
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-WDM67TP');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<!-- vendor:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/jquery.steps.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/titatoggle-dist-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/toastr.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="assets/styles/vendor/datatables/datatables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/dropzone/basic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/dropzone/dropzone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor/notify/angular-notify.min.css">
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/user/main.css">
<!-- endinject --> 
 </head>

<body class="mini-navbar">
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WDM67TP" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>  </noscript>
 <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
 <div ui-view="mainView" ng-class=""></div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below `XPath`:

```
//iframe[contains(@src, "id=GTM-WDM67TP")]
```